# Is this the recommended way to indent nested callbacks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, indentation

I've seen in some APIs documentation that they use the following syntax for nested callbacks:

```
webmap = new WebMap({
  portalItem: {
    id: "id"
  }
})
    .load()
        .then(function(instance){
            console.log(instance);
            view = new MapView({
              map: instance,
              container: "map"
            })
                .then(function(instance){

                })
            ;
        })
    ;
;
```

Is this the recommended way to syntax nested calls in Javascript?

Also, why? As someone who comes from Python, it seems so weird and unnecessary.

*If anyone is curious, I've seen this way of identation mostly in Semantic Ui's examples https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples*

Comment: I recommend you use a style guide, because code formatting is a subjective topic that can't have a canonical answer on Stack Overflow. People will vote based on their opinions instead of answer quality. FWIW I've never seen anyone format their code like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have deeply nested `then` calls, you might want to check if that is really necessary. In your case it is not. Move the inner `then` calls to the outer chain:

```
webmap = new WebMap({
    portalItem: {
        id: "id"
    }
}).load().then(function(instance){
    console.log(instance);
    // return (!) the promise, instead of applying a nested `then`
    return new MapView({
        map: instance,
        container: "map"
    });
}).then(function(instance){ // the `then` is now on the outer chain.

});
```

This way the depth of indentation remains reasonable, which is one of the advantages of promises (when you use them well).

Comment: Yes. Nested function calls are what .then() calls are intended to prevent.

Comment: Ah I see, that looks more promising

Comment: Good point about returning the inner promise from `MapView` and then handling that in the outer `then`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `Promise` interface (or something similar to it) so you aren't actually using nested callbacks in the traditional sense - though I see your `.then()` after the `MapView` construction would count as one.

The `then` invocations for the same sequence of events should be at the same indent level, a nested sequence of events should still have all of its events at the same level. This is how I would format it:

```
webmap = new WebMap( {
        portalItem: {
            id: "id"
        }
    } )
    .load()
    .then( function( instance ) {
        console.log( instance );
        view = new MapView( {
            map: instance,
            container: "map"
        } )
        .then( function( instance ) {

        } );
    } );
```

Note you can make this more succinct by using the arrow-function syntax:

```
webmap = new WebMap( {
        portalItem: {
            id: "id"
        }
    } )
    .load()
    .then( instance => {
        console.log( instance );
        view = new MapView( {
            map: instance,
            container: "map"
        } )
        .then( instance => {

        } );
    } );
```

Readability could be improved if you move the anonymous `options` objects out of the sequence of events, but as the `MapView` constructor's `options` takes the `instance` value that's not an option in this case.

But for the `WebMap` constructor you can:

```
var webMapOption = { portalItem: { id: "id" } };
webMap = new WebMap( webMapOptions )
    .load()
    .then( instance => ... );
```

Comment: There's a `}` missing in line 4, so now I'm confused as how it would be, would appreciate if you could fix that

Comment: @Mojimi Thank you. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Mojimi, I think it would be wise to revisit your decision to make this the correct answer. The code above is not formatted according to any kind of standard convention (and looks pretty lousy IMO). See how things are done in Standard JS - https://standardjs.com/rules.html - to get a feel.

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan Hmm, I'm not sure if I agree with all of the rules in standardjs - but I think it's a tad arrogant of them to call it "standard" when they aren't associated with the ECMA, nor do I see any of the JavaScript language designers' names in the Authors list either. I'm not opposed to standardjs, though.

Comment: @Dai I don't agree with all the rules either, but they give a better feel for what might count as a "recommend way" of approaching things than a code example that's spaced and indented in idiosyncratic and inconsistent ways.

Comment: This answer solved my problem, but I'll mark the other because the return was clever, I didn't know about that